# How to where query a method defined in rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

user.rb

```
scope :under_2500_value, -> { where(current_value: 0..2499) }
scope :under_5000_value, -> { where(current_value: 2500..4999) }

def current_value
  value * available.count / 100
end
```

available is another table that has a relationship with the user table as below.

```
has_many :users_availables
has_many :availables, through: :users_availables
```

In the rails console if I try

`User.under_2500_value`, it returns an error as below:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column users.current_value does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (users.curr...
```

Please help me find where I am going wrong

Made some edits in the question, didn’t understand the code correctly

Answer 1

```
scope :under_2500_value, -> { joins(:availables) { where('(value * availables.count / 100) in (?)', 0..2499) } }`


User.under_2500_value.last.current_value
```

The above query returns 7500 but it should have been between under 2500.

Comment: Because `under_2500_value` is an instance method, meaning it can only be called like `User.last.current_value`, but in your scope you're using it as if it were a column in the users table. What are `value` and `available` supposed to be? What's the column and what's the dynamic value there?

Comment: @AmoskalescapingfromRussia value and available are columns in user table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `current_value` is an instance method, meaning it can only be called like in an instance of the User model (like `User.last.current_value`), but in your scope you're using it as if it were a column in the users table.

You could try calculating the value right in the query and use the IN operator with the range values;

```
scope :under_2500_value, -> { where('(value * available / 100) in (?)', 0..2499) }
scope :under_5000_value, -> { where('(value * available / 100) in (?)', 2500..4999) }
```

See the similarity between both scopes? You could make a single one;

```
scope :under_value, ->(value) { where('(value * available / 100) in (?)', value) }

# To be used as
# User.under_value(0..2499)
```

Notice that if you're using Postgres you could make the `value * available / 100` calculation a generated column ([see](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html), it might translate to other RDBMS).

Comment: sorry I didn't read my code correctly, I have made some changes in the question, if you can help me further

Comment: I don't think that makes a difference, did you try with the code in any of the given answers?

Comment: the scope which you defined doesn't have count in it, available.counts\, value * available.count / 100

Availables is another table which has count field

Comment: users table has available_id as field in it

Comment: I think you have to add the join before; like `joins(:availables).where('(value * availables.count / 100) in (?)', value)`

Comment: I tried what you suggested. Please check the answer 1 in the question

Comment: I see your attempt won't work as expected. You should chain `joins` with `where` to use it in the same query (as in `joins(...).where(...)`), similar as in `SELECT ... FROM x JOIN y ON y.id = x.id WHERE ...`. I'm not sure what'll expect if you pass a block, probably it'll just be omitted.

Comment: Can you please update your answer just so I have a better understanding where I am going wrong?

Comment: Basically here `joins(:availables) { where('(value * availables.count / 100) in (?)', 0..2499) } }` you do `joins(:availables) { ... }` when it should be `joins(:availables).where(...)`. Check the implementation of [joins](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-joins). It's not expecting to receive a block (the `{ ... }` in that code makes a block)